# Laravel many to many relationship more then two data table

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7x and I know how to join two table by Laravel many to many relationship, but I need to join 5 to 6 table with a table. How can I join more then two database table by Laravel many to many relationship? (Eloquent Query)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an open question but what you may be looking for is Polymorphic Many-to-Many relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

This will allow you to connect multiple models together using a polymorphic pivot table.

Comment: Thank You for your help.